# How to get text that uses special characters in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anyone can help me?

I have a textarea, how can I get the special values of the textarea with php and jquery?

If, the input result of the textarea is:

> How to create a simple #program with #php for a #beginner.

How can I get characters only:
`#programming`, `#php` and `#beginner`

from this form:

`<form>`
 `<textarea class="textarea" id="textarea" name="textarea"></textarea>`
`<input type="submit" value="check">`
`</form>`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what have you tried, do you know anything about string manipulation?regex?

Comment: Hi, welcome, please show us what you have tried and accomplish. We are more here to help people resolve issues and bug. From you question right now i can think of 3 or 4 ways to achieve this. One mustfit your needs.

Comment: I've tried to remove the characters inputted with regex but if the problem above, I have never tried, because I am confused with it.

Comment: Knowing how/when you want to use this will dictate if you should use a js/jquery solution or a php solution.  If you want js/jquery please remove the php tag from your question (and vice versa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do some simple string manipulation:

```js
var x = 'How to create a simple #program with #php for a #beginner.';
var hash = [];
x.split(' ').forEach(function(v) {//split the string by space 
if(v.charAt(0) == '#')//test if the first character is the hash
    hash.push(v);//append it to the array
});
console.log(hash)
```

Comment: This is probably easier for a beginner to understand than a regex solution, but note that the example output in the question doesn't include trailing punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

```
var string = "How to create a simple #program with #php for a #beginner.";
var splitString = string.split(/#*\s/);
var result = [];
for(var i=0;i<splitString.length;i++){
    if(splitString[i].startsWith('#'))
        result.push(splitString[i]);
}
console.log(result);
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) like `/#[a-z0-9]+/gi` to do a case-insensitive global match of any "words" (one or more letters and numbers) that follow a hash character, perhaps using the [string `.match()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
var text = 'How to create a simple #program with #php for a #beginner.';
var tags = text.match(/#[a-z0-9]+/gi); 
console.log(tags);
```

The following binds a submit event listener to the form (I've given your form an ID for ease of selection from JS) to get the current value of the textarea at the time the form is submitted.

```js
document.getElementById("theForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {  
  e.preventDefault(); // for demo purposes cancel the form submission
  
  var text = document.getElementById("textarea").value; // get full text
  var tags = text.match(/#[a-z0-9]+/gi);                 // match the tags
  console.log(tags);
});
```

```html
<form id="theForm">
<textarea class="textarea" id="textarea" name="textarea">How to create a simple #program with #php for a #beginner.</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="check">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getSpecialWords(str)
{
    var words = str.split(" ");
    var character = "#";
    var result = [];

    for(var i=0; i<words.length; i++)
    {
        if(words[i].charAt(0) == character)
        {
            result.push(words[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

var str = "How to create a simple #program with #php for a #beginner.";


console.log( getWords(str) );
```

Comment: This won't work. Aside from the function names not matching, `.slice(0)` makes a copy of the whole string - did you mean to use `.charAt(0)`?

Comment: Yes, Thank you for the mention @nnnnnn